Constructing a centered distribution absolutely continuous with respect to uniform measure on the sphere with a pre-specified covariance?
Let $\mathcal{K}_n$ denote the space of $n \times n$, real symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $K$ having unit trace.
It is easy to verify that for each $K \in \mathcal{K}_n$, there exists a probability measure which is centered (mean zero) and supported on the $(n-1)$-sphere $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ having covariance equal to $K$.
Question: Let $\mu$ denote the uniform measure on the $(n-1)$-sphere. For every such $K \in \mathcal{K}_n$, does there exist a probability measure $\mu_K$ satisfying
$$
\mu_K \ll \mu, \quad 
\int_{S^{n-1}} x \, \mathrm{d} \mu_K(x) = 0, 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad
\int_{S^{n-1}} x x^T \, \mathrm{d} \mu_K(x) = K?
$$
If so, what is the density $\tfrac{\mathrm{d} \mu_K}{\mathrm{d} \mu}$?

Did you mean surface measure on $S^n$ (rather than Haar measure, which isn't defined due to the lack of a group structure)?

As @ChristianRemling comments, maybe you intend "rotation-invariant measure", etc...

I mean the uniform measure on the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Well, if you diagonalize the matrix then it is enough to consider the case of $K$ which has $1$ in the upper left corner and $0$ everywhere else. I bet this special case should be easier to handle by symmetry or something...
